On $- \dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta} (1-c+it) - \dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta} (c-it)$
In Gonek's paper the following is claimed: $$ - \dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta} (1-c+it) = \dfrac{\zeta'}{\zeta} (c-it) + \log \dfrac{t}{2 \pi} + O(\dfrac{1}{t})  \tag{$*$} $$
According to Titchmarsh's book Ch4, we have $\zeta(s) = \chi(s) \zeta(1-s)$ and $\chi(s) = 2^{s-1} {\pi}^s \sec \frac12 \pi s / \Gamma(s).$ Taking derivative of logarithm of the above and using $\Gamma/\Gamma' (s) = \log s + O(1/|s|)$ we have $-1/2 π \tan((π s)/2)$ extra on the right hand side of $(*)$. How can  $-1/2 π \tan((π s)/2)$ be absorbed in $O(\dfrac{1}{t})$?

What is the condition on $c$?

@Gary, $c=1+1/ \log 3x$ and $x>1$

Note that
\begin{align*}
 - \frac{\pi }{2}\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}s} \right) &=  - \frac{\pi }{2}\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}c - \frac{\pi }{2}{\rm i}t} \right) =  - \frac{\pi }{2}\frac{{\sin (\pi c) - {\rm i}\sinh (\pi t)}}{{\cos (\pi c) + \cosh (\pi t)}} \\&= \frac{\pi }{2}{\rm i} + \mathcal{O}({\rm e}^{ - \pi t} ) = \frac{\pi }{2}{\rm i} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right)
\end{align*}
and
$$
\log \left( {\frac{s}{{2\pi }}} \right) = \log \left( {\frac{{c - {\rm i}t}}{{2\pi }}} \right) = \log \left( {\frac{t}{{2\pi }}} \right) - \frac{\pi }{2}{\rm i} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right),
$$
as $t\to+\infty$.
